# Upper limit of precision in mpmath-python

Tags: python, precision, mpmath

When in `python` and `mpmath` one's code starts with

```
from mpmath import mp 

mp.dps =200
```

My question is whether -depending on one's hardware- does  there exist an upper limit to `mp.dps` and how can one find this uper limit.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the actual precision is stored in binary bits and not decimal digits. `mp.dps()` automatically does the conversion to binary bits.

By default, `mpmath` uses the Python arbitrary-precision integers as the basis for its arithmetic. There are no limitations other than the memory in your system or your patience.

If you have `gmpy2` installed, `mpmath` will automatically use the faster integer type based on the GMP library. The GMP library has a maximum precision of 2^32 - 1 bits (roughly 1.29E9 decimal digits) on 32-bit systems and 2^37 - 1 bits (roughly 4.14E10 decimal digits) on 64-bit systems.

I'm not aware of any other limits.